# Using the AWS Java SDK, is it possible to unassociate the role tied to a stack?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I have a cloud formation stack that was created through automation.  A shared automation role is configured for this stack to assume when changes are made.

We are changing our workflow so we want users to execute the stacks so they only are able to provision resources based on their own permissions.

I'm looking for a way to unnassociate the current role from the existing stacks so future updates are performed using the user's permissions as outlined in the documentation:

> If you don't specify a value, AWS CloudFormation uses the role that was previously associated with the stack. 
>   If no role is available, AWS CloudFormation uses a temporary session that is generated from your user credentials.

I've looked through all the CloudFormation API JavaDocs to find some way of unnassociating the role from the stack but cannot find one.  Even deleting the role doesn't work.  If you delete the role, the stack fails to update all together because the role doesn't exist.

I've also looked for a way to generate a temporary role that has the same permissions has the user but cannot find a way to do that either.